# Listen for event on new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

My application uses `oauth` to allow a user to login to Salesforce, and after logging in, they can access the application. What currently happens is:

- The user clicks the "login" link, and is redirected to Salesforce
- The user logs into Salesforce, and is redirected to the URL I specified
- My server processes the request and redirects them to the home page

What I would like to do is this:

- The user clicks on the "login" link, and a new window (`window.open`) with the Salesforce login page appears
- The user logs in, and is redirected to the URL I specified
- Once the server redirects to the home page, the home page fires a `success` or `logged_in` event in the window, which the original page listens for and interprets

This is what I've made so far (assume there is `<button id="login">Log in</button>`)

```
$('button#login').on('click', function() {
    var popup = window.open('/auth/salesforce', 'login', '...');
    popup.addEventListener('success', function() {
        popup.close();
        alert('Logged in');
    });
});
```

and in the home page, I added to the section that displays when a user is logged in successfully:

```
var event = window.createEvent('loginSuccess');
event.initEvent('success', true, true); 
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

However, the `success` event is never fired. How would I fire a `success` event in the home page, to alert the original page that the user is successfully logged in?

Edit: I noticed there is the `window.postMessage` method, as referenced in [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage). Is this what I should use? Or should I use another method to capture a successful login event on the newly created `window`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through my research, I found that the best way to accomplish this, at least if I don't need to support IE browsers, is to look at the `window.opener` value, and if it exists, run a function defined in `window.opener`. For example,

```
if (window.opener) {
    window.opener.userIsLoggedIn();
}
window.close();
```

`userIsLoggedIn()` would be defined in the parent window that opened the new pop-up.

With that said, a couple caveats: in certain IE environments, `window.opener` will lose its value due to some security restrictions, thus making `window.opener` `null` and never firing the `userIsLoggedIn()` method on the parent window. In these cases, I would listen for the `close` event on the created window, and if the `userIsLoggedIn()` function hasn't fired, refresh the page. A second caveat is that you will only be able to call `window.opener.userIsLoggedIn()` if and only if it matches the Same Origin Policy; see [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) on the subject. If this poses an issue and you cannot work your application around these restrictions, see [this project](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM) for possible workarounds/hacks.

I don't have a need to support IE so I have not created this code, but if the `window.onclose` method fires in IE, listen for the [`window.onclose`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclose?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FWindow.onclose) event and perform your checks after this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I recently just put the same OAuth in our application. Don't try to use a new window to auth users just like all the social networks just let the page that the user is on go to the auth screen and then redirect you back... The only other way this can be done (and i'm not sure salesforce has this yet) is a javascript auth process.